# matlab - how to get single random number?

Tags: matlab, random

I need to generate random number between `-0.1` and `0.1`. I tried:

```
x = randn(-1,1)*0.1
```

But this just gives me:

```
Empty matrix: 0-by-1
```

So How can I just generate random number?..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rand()` to get a single random number between `0` and `1`.

If you have one of those, then `a + b * rand()` is a random number between `a` and `a+b`. In your case, you could use

```
>>> x = 0.2 * rand() - 0.1
0.060971
```

The function `randn` as opposed to `rand` generates *normally distributed* random numbers. You can never guarantee that a normally distributed random number will be bounded, so they are not appropriate for your case.